# Impedir que una imagen de una página aparezca en los resultados de búsqueda de google

Tags: seo, hosting, google-search

Tengo el siguiente archivo robots.txt alojado en mi página web:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /descargas/
Disallow: /img/avatar300x300.jpg
```

A pesar de escribir `Disallow: /img/avatar300x300.jpg` sigue apareciendo la imagen si busco por google imagenes. ¿Cómo hago para eliminar la imagen de la búsqueda de google?¿Tengo que añadir en el fichero robots lo siguiente?:
  
    `User-Agent: Googlebot-Image
    Disallow: /img/avatar300x300.jpg`
Al poner User-Agent: * y Disallow entiendo que no debería aparecer la imagen.

Comment: Ojo que si la imagen ha estado disponible anteriormente google la puede estar cacheando temporalmente.

Comment: eso es...espero que temporalmente. He actualizado el robots.txt, subido a mi página y avisado a google de ello. Pero sigue apareciendo en las búsquedas. No se si porque en el fichero no especifico User-Agent: Googlebot-Image o como tú bien dices, porque google está cacheando temporalmente la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Podemos decir que en Google hay dos tipos de eliminación de los resultados de búsqueda.

### A. Hacer eliminación permanente

De acuerdo con Google, indicar que las páginas o imágenes no se indexen es el **menos eficaz de los métodos** para lograrlo:

> La herramienta Eliminar URL tiene sólo un efecto temporal. Para
>   eliminar el contenido de búsqueda de Google o una URL permanente, debe
>   realizar una o más de las acciones adicionales siguientes:
>
> - Remover o actualizar el contenido real de su sitio (imágenes, páginas, directorios) y asegúrese de que su servidor devuelve 404 (no
>     se encontró) o 410 (Gone) ,  cuando intente acceder al recurso que
>     quiere eliminar, si el mismo tiene acceso HTTP. Para archivos que no
>     sean HTML (como archivos PDF) deben ser retirados por completo de su
>     servidor.
> - Bloquear el acceso a los contenidos, por ejemplo, exigiendo una contraseña.
> - Indicar que las páginas que quiere retirar no se indexen, usando la etiqueta [`noindex meta tag`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708). Esto es menos seguro que los otros
>     métodos.

### B. Eliminación temporal

Los pasos para hacer eliminación temporal son indicados en el enlace de más abajo. Pero ten en cuenta lo siguiente, afirmado por Google en el [apartado](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419) donde indica cómo eliminar *temporalmente* contenido de los resultados de búsqueda:

> Las solicitudes que se aprueban duran solo 90 días aproximadamente.
>   Después de este tiempo, la información podrá aparecer en los
>   resultados de búsqueda de Google (consulta la sección Conseguir una
>   eliminación permanente). Para poder utilizar esta herramienta, debes
>   poseer una propiedad de Search Console que se corresponda con la URL.
>   En caso contrario, consulta esta página.

---

**Cualquiera de los dos tipos de eliminación que quieras hacer [son explicados aquí](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419) paso a paso**.